# Error: arguments imply differing number of rows through ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I am working on a set of google web data for both customers and prospects, and I want to create a column to classify customers vs. prospects. I can identify them through a column of "acquisition date". If the row has that date, it indicates that ID is a customer, otherwise prospects. So I tried using the following code by using ddply function in package plyr:("acquidate" is the column containing date of acquisition,I want to show 1 for customer and 0 for prospect in the new column created)

```
data2<-ddply(data2,.(gsid),transform,custindex2=ifelse(is.na(data2$acquidate),0,1))
```

But R shows the error message like:Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1557057

However, when I tried the following code, it worked out:

```
data2$custindex<-ifelse(is.na(data2$acquidate),0,1)
```

I just don't understand why ddply can't function well for this project. Will appreciate it very much if anybody can provide a solution!

Comment: Can you try `ifelse(is.na(aquidate),0,...`

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it worked. I am just wondering how to make it work through ddply. Sorry, I maybe a little too picky :P

Comment: I was referring to the one in `ddply` command, ie. instead of `data2$aquidate`.  Not tested without an example though.

Comment: For example `data(mtcars); mtcars$disp[4:8] <- NA; ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), transform,newcol=ifelse(is.na(disp), 0, 1))`.  BTW, this could be done without grouping and also `ifelse`. ie. `with(mtcars, (!is.na(disp))+0)`